# Trying to sum 3 input values using <amp-bind-macro>

Tags: ampscript

***AMP-SCRIPT*** gurus!

I used a <**amp-bind-macro**> tag (from an example) to multiply the value of an <**input type="number"**> field by a constant value. It worked! Now, I'm trying to multiply different values from **different INPUTs** and I cannot:

- find a way to reference those values.
- pass those values to the (ehm...) function.
- enjoy my first hours playing with AMP-SCRIPT.

Simply put...

I need to assign the result of this operation to a <**span**>

<**span**> = (12 + (**inputA** * 8) + (**inputB** * 2) + (**inputC** * 5))

Before you *ROFLOL*, that is not a code at all. I was just trying to picture the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For inputs, you need bind the value via `AMP.setState()`

Then in `<amp-bind-macro />` expression, just call those variables, don't need `arguments` here.

Here's example for sum 2 input:

```
<amp-bind-macro id="sum" expression="numberA + numberB">

<input type="number" value="0" on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({ numberA: event.value })">
<input type="number" value="0" on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({ numberB: event.value })">

<div>
  Result <span [text]="sum()">0</span>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what? I found how. Basically, you need to:

- initialize variables with values.
- add the macro (like the function, its parameters and the math operations.
- tell each INPUT to update its corresponding variable.
- assign the result to the SPAN.